# How to find widest paths collection on a directed weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, path, bigdata

Consider the following graph:

[image]

nodes 1 to 6 are connected with a transition edge that have a direction and a volume property (red numbers). I'm looking for the right algorithm to find paths with a high volume. In the above example the output should be:

1. Path: [4,5,6] with a minimal volume of 17
2. Path: [1,2,3] with a
   minimal volume of 15

I've looked at [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) but I'm not sure it's the right approach.

Any resources, comments or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The real question is when to use Dijksta's algorithm or when to use another algorithm like Floyd-Warshall.  Really Floyd is a subset of Dijkstra only looking for one shortest instead of every path.  You want "High Volume" but did say how many paths you want.  Dijksta will get every path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, basically I want all paths sorted by volume, then get the top 10

Comment: Then I would use dijkstra's algorithm to get every path.  As I run dijkstra, I would add paths to list in sorted order.  When I get to 11 path I would only add new path if it is more than minimum item in List.  with Dijkstra you run it from every node unitl you get to a node already visited or end then add up volume of path.  Don't know if you have loops.

Comment: So the top paths in your example would be [1,2] and [4,5], is that right?

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I want. In my example path 4,5,6 should be the winner, and I don't sum the volume I use the minimum volume as the total volume of the path. Can I still use Dijkstra?  Can you please add pseudo code?

Comment: As @Beta points out: You need some other constraints on your paths, otherwise the widest paths are simply the single-edge path(s) with the largest volume.

Comment: *Why* should [4,5,6] (with a score of 17) beat [4,5] (with a score of 20)?

Comment: You guys are right, that's where I'm lost. To the human eye it's obvious that 4,5 is just a partial part of a large path. What would you suggest?

Comment: Only *you* know what you're actually trying to accomplish! ;)

Comment: As @j_random_hacker said, your question is not clear. You say "to the human eye, it's obvious that 4,5 is just a partial path of a large path." But to my human eye, it's clear that [4,5,6] is also just a partial path of [4,5,6,1]. Just trying to figure out what you're doing, I have two guesses: 1) Do the paths need a minimum length? 2) Are you trying to find the set of paths that spans the graph?

Comment: @Kittsil [4,5,6,1] cannot be a path since there there is no edge from 6 -> 1, basically I'm trying to find "the beaten paths" of the graph, for example: the volume could represent travel count between 2 points

Comment: @Shlomi Ah, I thought that edge 1 -> 6 was going the other way. But the point remains; [1,2,3,5] is a valid example. By "beaten" paths, you mean you are looking for paths in which the minimum weight edge is above some threshold? If so, I can give you a very efficient algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I need to find the weight threshold first, for example at the graph above 15 should be the minimum. But if the values are different it could be 1500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finding a beaten graph:**

In the comments, you clarify that you are looking for "beaten" paths. I am assume this means that you are trying to contrast the paths with the average; for instance, looking for paths which can support weight at least e*w, where 0<e and w is the average edge weight. (You could have any number of contrast functions here, but the function you choose does not affect the algorithm.)

Then the algorithm to find all paths that meet this condition is incredibly simple and only takes O(m) time:

1. Loop over all edges to find the average weight. (Takes O(m) time.)
2. Calculate the threshold based on the average. (Takes O(1) time.)
3. Remove all edges which do not support the threshold weight. (Takes O(m) time.)
4. Any path in the resulting graph will be a member of the "widest path collection."

**Example:**

Consider that e=1.5. That is, you require that a beaten path support at least 1.5x the average edge weight. Then in graph you provided, you will loop over all the edges to find their average weight, and multiply this by e:

```
((20+4)+15+3+(2+20)+(1+1+17))/9 = 9.2
9.2*1.5 = 13.8
```

Then you loop over all edges, removing any that have weight less than 13.8. Any remaining paths in the graph are "beaten" paths.

**Enumerating all beaten paths:**

If you then want to find the set of beaten paths with maximal length (that is, they are not "parts" of paths), the modified graph is must be a DAG (because a cycle can be repeated infinite times). If it is a DAG, you can find the set of all maximal paths by:

1. In your modified graph, select the set of all source nodes (no incoming edges).
2. From each of these source nodes, perform a DFS (allowing repeated visits to the same node).
3. Every time you get to a sink node (no outgoing edges), write down the path that you took to get here.

This will take up to O(IncompleteGamma[n,1]) time (super exponential), depending on your graph. That is, it is not very feasible.

**Finding the widest paths:**

An actually much simpler task is to find the widest paths between every pair of nodes. To do this:

1. Start from the modified graph.
2. Run [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Algorithm)'s, using `pathWeight(i,j,k+1) = max[pathWeight(i,j,k), min[pathWeight(i,k+1,k), pathWeight(k+1,j,k)]]` (that is, instead of adding the weights of two paths, you take the minimum volume they can support).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I need to find the weight threshold first, for example at the graph above 15 should be the minimum. But if the values are different it could be 1500.

Comment: @Shlomi That is what I meant by "compare to the average." It is not difficult at all, and can be done in O(m) time. I'll throw it into the answer.

Comment: @Shlomi Finding the weight threshold is extremely trivial. You need to decide what conditions you want for an edge to meet that threshold (for instance, being some fraction larger than average, or more than one standard deviation above the mean, etc.). Once you do that, you can remove all edges that do not meet this condition and find the paths in any way you choose: total enumeration, brute force, Floyd-Warshall's, etc. The thing that made your question difficult to answer was that you were unclear about what you meant by "high volume."

Comment: Thanks for the effort... I'll give out a go